# sqlite3 creating trigger in android

Tags: android, sqlite

I created table using this command :

```
CREATE TABLE projects( p_id integer primary key autoincrement, p_name text not null , p_desc text ,p_created_at datetime null , p_updated_at datetime null );
```

now i want to create a trigger on which the p_created_at and p_updated_at field will be updated,,,so i wrote

This is before insert query i wrote but gives me error

```
create trigger trigger_project before insert on projects
for each row begin
set new.p_created_at=now();
set new.p_updated_at=now();
end;
```

This gives me error

```
Error: near "set": syntax error
```

Any help is appreciated,, thnks

instead of now(); also tried datetime('now');
but still no luck :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [doc](http://sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html) you can't use just set, you need to write a statment, like

`UPDATE myTable set column1 = value1`

Comment: then how can we simulate this kind of behaviour,,is there a workaround this,,,,still not able to get this right,,,